# Откуда правильно удалять элемент списка ObservableCollection<>?

Tags: c#

```
    private ObservableCollection<RecentlyFileModel> _recentlyList;
    public ObservableCollection<RecentlyFileModel> Items
    {
        get { return _recentlyList; }
        set
        {
            _recentlyList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
```

Вот я хочу удалить строку в коллекции. Откуда мне правильней ее удалять? Из `Items` или `_recentlyList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да без разницы, в общем-то, что `Items`, что `_recentlyList` - на один и тот же адрес будут ссылаться. Вьюху `ObservableCollection`, всё равно, уведомит сама.